# How to prevent duplicate entry in database on page refresh after posting form in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am submitting a form on submit event in mvc 4.0. after submitting form is posted to its action and record is created. after creating record when i refresh the page then another duplicate record is created.

I already used following but not succeed:

```
ModelState.Clear();
ModelState.SetModelValue("Key", new ValueProviderResult(null, string.Empty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
ModelState.Remove("Key");
```

I don't want to use AJAX form Post and also don't want to redirect on another page.

Is there any way that we use in asp.net like `!Page.IsPostBack()` in mvc4.0.

I dont want to use session also.

(Microsoft blowing about MVC that MVC does not have any view state like asp.net but now I don't think so).

Comment: Page.IsPostBack doesn't prevent this, even though you write code saying !Page.IsPostBack, as the browser redo the same exact requrest, it will be a postback and will insert the record again.

Comment: I am asking for solution like !Page.IsPostBack()

Comment: Where will the state be saved? Browser does not modify a request when reloading page, you have no sessions, no cookies, I assume. So your server-side will never know it is a duplicate. You have to either write into database or redirect somewhere or store this state elsewhere.

Comment: I already reloading page with **mymodel=new mymodel()**

Comment: Please write down your detail code, I think it should be help to answer your question.

Comment: There is no Postback analog in MVC, it is a Web Forms artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the form using Ajax.post. Construct your form tag like below.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "anyFormName" }))
```

Call the ajax post from the page.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerName/Index",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#anyFormName").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divFormContainer").html(data);
        }
    });
```

In controller create the Index method like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
{
   // Put the form post logics here....
   // Build the model for the view...
   return PartialView("Index", model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect after succesful update to index action. In this case refresh will resend request to index action instead post to update action. This pattern is known as "Post-Redirect-Get" pattern.
Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(SomeModelViewClass model)
{
   //some code that save data to db
   return RedirectToAction("index", new {id=model.Id});
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
   //some code that get data from db by id
   return View(model);
}
```